# Spring Web flux Mongo query

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, mongorepository

Hi I am new to Spring web flux and facing the issue regarding Mongo reactive query.

I have following structure of my model class

```
public class Users implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<Email>emails;
}


public class Email implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String address;
    boolean verified;
}
```

Now I have to query that if given email exists or not in the mong document as email filed is list of email as given above.

Can any one please me on this?

I have written the following query on repository

```
@Query(value = "{'emails.address' : ?0 }")
    Mono<Users> findByEmails(String address);
```

Comment: hi what is the issue are you facing to find emails  @Query("{'users.emails.address': ?0}") Mono <Users> findByEmailAddress(final String address) should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
@Query("{'users.emails.address': ?0}") 
Mono <Users> findUserByEmailAddress(final String address)
```

Comment: how can i be sure that only one row should be come in this case.

Comment: also why are you using user.email , i have already marked my model @Document(collection='users'). is it correct?

Comment: sorry if you are expeecting list of values use Flux<Users> and even though you mark this with @Document((collection='users') this is for mongo to know the collection and the query should contain users since it contains the user object